# Find three consecutive positive integers a,b and c such that a+b is a perfect square and b+c is a perfect cube.

Tags: integers, square-numbers

Find three consecutive positive integers a,b and c such that a+b is a perfect square and b+c is a perfect cube.

Any ideas on how to begin?

Comment: Hint: $a+b=2b-1$, and $b+c=2b+1$.

Answer (score 6):

$b=a+1$ and $c=a+2$. Write:
$$2a+1=m^2,\ 2a+3=n^3$$
$$m^2+2=n^3$$
We need to look for a square that is 2 less than a cube. The squares are:
$$1, 4, 9, 16, \mathbf{25}, 36, \dots$$
The cubes are:
$$1, 8, \mathbf{27}, 64, 125, \dots$$
We see that $m^2=25$ satisfies the condition, so that $a=(25-1)/2=12$. Hence the consecutive integers with the given properties are 12, 13 and 14.

Comment: Even more that's the only solution of the equation $m^2 + 2 = n^3$ excluding $(m,n) = (-5,3)$ for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Stefan4024 How do we know it's the only solution?

Comment: Factor the LHS in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ which is a UFD. The proof is not trivial, but you can find it easily on the Internet.

Comment: @Stefan4024: "you can find it easily on the Internet" is as bad as "for obvious reasons"! I wouldn't know how to search for such a proof. Can you provide a link?

Comment: @TonyK [Here you go!](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) After all I don't intend serving everything on a plate for people, when all you need to write is "Mordell Equation" on Google. Or even "m^2 + 2 = n^3". As for the previous comment it's obvious that $(m,n) = (-5,3)$ doesn't provide us with anything new. In case you understood it wrongly I was referring to the exclusion of $(m,n) = (-5,3)$ ;)

Comment: @Stefan4024: I did wonder whether "for obvious reasons" perhaps referred to that. But you have just provided a replacement Stefanism for it: 'all you need to write is "Mordell Equation" on Google'. So obvious! Also, I tried googling "m^2 + 2 = n^3", and I got nothing helpful at all in the first two pages.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the easiest things for you to do would be to search odd cube as b+c and check whether they fit the pattern.
Example: the second odd cube is 27. If b = 13 and c = 14, then a = 12 and a + b = 25, which is a perfect square, so the triplet (12, 13, 14) fits the pattern.
Based on the final digit of cubes and squares, the last digit of any cubes worth checking should end in 1, 3 or 7, as these are the only odd last digits that could fit the square condition.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$, $x^3-y^2=2$ according to the given question, where $x=a+b$ and $y=b+c$. However, $x^3 \equiv 0,\pm1 \pmod4$ and $y^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod4$.

So to satisfy the given equation, the following must hold: $$x^3-y^2\equiv 2 \pmod4$$

For this means that the required $x,y$ are such that $x^3 \equiv -1\equiv 3 \pmod4$ and $y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod4$. That is, the required forms are $$x^3=4n+3$$ $$y^2=4n+1$$

See if this helps.

Comment: I would say it doesn't help very much. Also, what on earth does your first sentence mean?

Comment: @TonyK Does it serve well now? Thanks for the previous opinion.

Comment: That's much better :-)